# php_oci8.dll not registered on xampp

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, oracle10g, php-5.2

I am so confused about this php_oci8.dll library.

I already set PATH varible.
I am sure that php_oci8.dll already exist in the xampp/php/ext folder.
I am sure that i already uncomment extension=php_oci8.dll.

The problem is:
1. When i access the phpinfo() i dont see any oci8 loaded BUT, when i run with cmd command `php --ri oci8`, it say enabled

[image]

2. I cant use any php function to connect to oracle database such `oci_connect()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it already. Turns out that i need to uncomment 2 php.ini files.

1. C:/xampp/php/php.ini
2. C:/xampp/apache/bin/php.ini

Uncomment the "extension=php_oci8.dll" on the both files.